# Remote Desktop Connection session to windows server 2008 problem with licensing

Tags: macos

I cannot log in with my credentials using Remote Desktop Connection v2.1.1 (up to date) session to windows server 2008. Error states there's a problem with licensing. Tried from two different machines, both running latest version of RDC both running on OSX 10.6.8. This connection tested OK and ran for about two weeks. No updates have been made on either machine, or the remote server I'm trying to access. However, I can do this from a Windows machine using same credentials and IP address without a problem...

Any ideas on what to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try another RDC app like CoRD. This will help you rule out the RDC 2.1.1 app

Comment: Thanks, it works with CoRD. Guess I'm submitting a case to makers of RDC

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging on with an account that is an administrator on the windows server 2008 box? Try connecting with the /console switch. 
If it's a licensing error it is most likely a terminal services licensing error. I believe that windows xp/7/8 have a built-in terminal severices CAL. If you are not connecting to the 2k8 server as an administrator from a mac you would need a terminal server CAL.
You should see Terminal Services Licensing errors on the 2008 server if you need a CAL to connect.